# Setting Twitter and Facebook statuses

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

Are there any C# libraries for integrating Facebook status updates and twitter updates (preferably with url shortening) in Monotouch without too much heavy lifting?

I know there is a Facebook kit already for objective-C, I really only need status updating however.

Answer (score 1):

For twitter, [TweetSharp](http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/) is Mono 2.6 compatible, does url shortening, and works with MonoTouch.

For Facebook try [.Net Facebook API](http://facebook.codeplex.com/) on codeplex (Specifically just the Facebook.dll and not the web stuff).  It is open source and you could run the lib through [MoMA](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) to see if anything needs to be changed/updated to be compatible.